# PSQL row limit on export table

Tags: postgresql, psql

I was connecting to another team's Postgres DB and was trying to export data for some debugging purposes.
I noticed when I ran the below command, I got 50K rows

```
psql -t "sslmode=require host=MY_HOST port=MY_PORT dbname=MY_DB user=MY_USER password=MY_PASSWORD" -c "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;" -o EXPORT.txt
```

```
$ cat EXPORT.txt | wc -l
   50000
```

But when I log in and check the row count, it was 94K

```
psql -t "sslmode=require host=MY_HOST port=MY_PORT dbname=MY_DB user=MY_USER password=MY_PASSWORD"
MY_DB=> SELECT count(*) FROM MYTABLE;
    94508
```

What is the row count for exporting the table using psql shell?
Is this a hard limit?
I wrote a bash script to loop using limit and offset as a work around.

Comment: No, there is no such limit imposed in `psql`. Is it possible you have defined `FETCH_COUNT` in your `.psqlrc`?

Comment: Thanks... I will check with the other team..... Seems like I can also do something like
```
postgres=# \set FETCH_COUNT 1000
```
Thanks for the tip....